# a line from vhost setting

Tags: linux, apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/html/web/yourcharmstyle.com/htdocs/:/tmp/"
```

what the line meaning and do? thank you. why it add `/:/tmp/` ? why it adds the line?

Answer (score 0):

`:` is a separator here between two different paths -- the path to the docroot under `/var/www`, and the temporary directory `/tmp`.

Comment: why it add that line? what's the effection to add it? thank you